# Why does this function print what it does?

Tags: java

If `f` and `g` are defined like this:

```
void f(int[] x, int[] y, int p, int q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        x[i] = 2 * x[i];
    }
    x = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    y[3] = 5;
    p = q + 1;
}

void g() {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] y = {9, 7, 6, 5};
    f(y, x, y[0], x[0]);
    for (int p : x) {
        System.out.print("" + p + " ");
    }
    for (int q : y) {
        System.out.print("" + q + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

then if you run `g()`, it prints `1 2 3 5 18 14 12 10`, and I don't know why.

How do `p` and `q` even come into the equation?

Comment: p and q are just variables. What the for loop is doing is saying for every item in x do something

Comment: Step through the program, either on paper or with a debugger.

Comment: That is a really overly complicated example for a beginner but if you want to understand all of it right now you may find it helpful to google the following (with a java attached to each): "immutability", "reference types", "loops", "function calls", probably best in reverse order -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do `p` and `q` even come into the equation?

Assuming you're asking about the parameters to method `f`:
`p = q + 1;` is a meaningless statement, since [Java is "pass-by-value"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5221149).

---

Also, the following code is meaningless for the same reason, since `x` is reassigned to a new array, the changes to `x` doesn't affect the values in the caller.

```
x = new int[5]; // caller is unaffected by this
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    x[i] = 0; // meaningless, since new int[5] is pre-initialized to all zeroes
}
```

---

Last part of confusion is caused by the swap of `x` and `y`. Method `f(x, y)` is called as `f(y, x)` in method `g`, so f's `x` is really g's `y`.

To help differentiate them, let's rename parameters of `f` to `a` and `b`. The new code (removing meaningless statements and parameters) is then:

```
void f(int[] a, int[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        a[i] = 2 * a[i];
    }
    b[3] = 5;
}
```

As you can see, it doubles the values of first argument, and changes 4th (index 3) value of second argument to `5`.

Which means that method call `f(y, x)` in method g will double values of `y` and change `x[3]` to `5`.

`x = {1, 2, 3, 4}` becomes `x = {1, 2, 3, 5}`
`y = {9, 7, 6, 5}` becomes `y = {18, 14, 12, 10}`

Which leads to printed output: `1 2 3 5 18 14 12 10`

Comment: Thankyou so much, it was the sneaky swap of x and y that was throwing me off.

Comment: @user431587 Oh yes, that's an easy-to-overlook detail.

Answer (score 0):

p and q are just variables which are used in for loop.
Here the code uses "for each loop" which a variant of "for loop".

In **for each loop ** instead of declaring and initializing a loop counter variable, we declare a variable that is the same data type as the base type of the array or collection, followed by a semi-colon, which is then followed by the array or collection name.

to understand how for each loop work check out this answer-> [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: I think the question is about the `p` and `q` parameters of method `f`, not about the loop iterator variables.